# TabBarView dentro de um SliverToBoxAdapter

Tags: flutter, dart

Preciso adicionar uma tabbarview dentro do SliverToBoxAdapter, mas nada que eu tente funciona. Quero gerar um gráfico para cada aba, mas não consigo nem inserir uma mensagem qualquer. Segue abaixo meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
class StatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StatsScreenState createState() => _StatsScreenState();
}

class _StatsScreenState extends State<StatsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Palette.primaryColor,
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      // design barra superior
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _buildHeader(),
          _buildRegionTabBar(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  SliverPadding _buildHeader() {
    return SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Text(
        'Estatisticas',
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 25.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  SliverToBoxAdapter _buildRegionTabBar() {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
          child: TabBar(
            tabs:[
              Tab(text: 'Brasil'),
              Tab(text: 'Mundo'),    
            ],
          ),
          
      ),
      );
      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação

> Now that you have tabs, display content when a tab is selected. For
> this purpose, use the TabBarView widget.

*Agora que você tem guias, exiba o conteúdo quando uma guia for selecionada. Para isso, use o widget TabBarView.*

```
TabBarView(
  children: [
    Icon(Icons.directions_car),
    Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
    Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
  ],
);
```

Exemplos:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

http://www.macoratti.net/19/10/flut_tabbar1.htm